# Silverlight (3) best practices

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I'm planning a greenfield project using silverlight 3. I was wondering if there are anything like the "smart client software factory" for silverlight...

Cheers,
Ali

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there is. It's called Prism. Take a look at the [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) site

Answer (score 1):

Somebody recommended this cool site to me earlier in the day. Hope it can help you.

[www.silverlightcream.com](http://www.silverlightcream.com)

Also, you can pretty much apply the same patters from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx) to your silverlight 3 app.